# Is one norm property: $p(v)=0 \iff v=0$ or positive definiteness?

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm confused as to seeing different requirements for norms.

Triangle eq. and homogeneity seem to be in all, but the last property seems to be either:

$p(v)=0 \iff v=0$ or positive definiteness

How are these related/equivalent?

---

It seems that positive definiteness may be able to capture the rule about norm having to be positive, while also capturing the zero element property, both at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Positive definiteness of $p$ states that $p(v) = 0 \iff v = 0$ *and* $p(v) \geq 0$ for all $v \in V$. This is definitely required for every norm.

If you're reading the Wikipedia article, $p(v) \geq 0$ for all $v \in V$ is implicitly encoded since $p$ is a function $p: V \to [0, \infty)$, hence you only need to include $p(v) = 0 \iff v = 0$ as an additional requirement.

Comment: Indeed. I don't like that hidden requirement in the wiki article. In most similar definitions there is already an implicit (semi-hidden) requirement that the the operation must be defined for all elements of the set. The norm definition on wiki has another implicit requirement that is somewhat unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. A norm is a mapping $\lVert\cdot\rVert\colon V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, satisfying the following properties. For all $v,w\in V$, you have the triangle inequality $\lVert v+w\rVert\le\lVert v\rVert+\lVert w\rVert$. For all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R},v\in V$ you have absolute homogenity, i.e. $\lVert \lambda v\rVert=\lvert\lambda\vert\lVert v\rVert$. Then we require either of the following properties:

- $\lVert v\rVert=0\Rightarrow v=0$ for $v\in V$,
- $\lVert v\rVert\ge0$ for all $v\in V$ with equality iff $v=0$.

I've seen either of these two properties be referred to as positive-definiteness, so I won't name them. The second property trivially implies the former property. For the other direction, notice that if $\lVert v\rVert<0$ for some $v\in V$, you would - by absolute homogenity - have $\lVert-v\rVert=\lvert-1\rvert\lVert v\rVert=\lVert v\rVert<0$ and then - by the triangle inequality - $0=\lVert0\rVert=\lVert v+(-v)\rVert\le\lVert v\rVert+\lVert-v\rVert<0$, a contradiction, so the norm is definitely non-negative. The equivalency $\lVert v\rVert=0\Leftrightarrow v=0$ then follows from the first property as $\lVert0\rVert=\lVert\lambda0\rVert=\lvert\lambda\rvert\lVert0\rVert$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and hence $\lVert0\rVert=0$.